# svm classifier for text classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

I am trying with `SVC` classifier to classify text.

```
        #self.vectorizer = HashingVectorizer(non_negative=True)
        #self.vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5, stop_words='english')
        self.hasher = FeatureHasher(input_type='string',non_negative=True)
        from sklearn.svm import SVC
        self.clf =  SVC(probability=True)
        for text in self.data_train.data:
            text = self.modifyQuery(text.decode('utf-8','ignore'))
            training_data.append(text)

        raw_X = (self.token_ques(text) for text in training_data)
        #X_train = self.vectorizer.transform(training_data)
        X_train = self.hasher.transform(raw_X)
        y_train = self.data_train.target
        self.clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

test classifier:

```
        raw_X = (self.token_ques(text) for text in test_data)
        X_test = self.hasher.transform(raw_X)
        #X_test = self.vectorizer.transform(test_data)
        pred = self.clf.predict(X_test)
        print("pred=>", pred)
        self.categories = self.data_train.target_names
        for doc, category in zip(test_data, pred):
            print('%r => %s' % (doc, self.categories[category]))
        index = 1
        predict_prob = self.clf.predict_proba(X_test)
        for doc, category_list in zip(test_data, predict_prob):
            #print values
```

I tried with hashing, feature, tfidf vectorizer but still it gives wrong answer for all queries (class with highest datasize comes as answer). While using naive bayes it gives correct result as per class and input query.

Am I doing anything wrong in code?

**Update**

I have total 8 classes, and each class having 100-200 lines of sentences. One class with 480 lines. This class always comes as a answer currently

Comment: What are your output categories? How many, and how imbalanced are they?

Comment: @clf: updated the description. please check